# Two datatable to nested list<myclass>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, recursion, datatable, treeview

I have data in two `DataTable`s:

```
dtTree = "SELECT UnqID, category FROM ExpressionCategorys" 

dtTreeInner = "SELECT Name FROM Expressions WHERE FK_Category = '{" & dtTree.Rows(i)("UnqID").ToString & "}'
```

My problem is, I can do this long way of coding given below, but how do I pass data from `DataTable`s to the `List` (since `dtTree` is the parent node and `dtTreeInner` is the child node)?

```
-Expressions          (topnode static)
--Standard            (childnode of Expressions - this data comes from  dtTree) 
--- ApplicationRef    (childnode - this data comes from  dtTreeInner ) 
--- ApplicationStat   (childnode - this data comes from  dtTreeInner ) 
--- Longdate          (childnode - this data comes from  dtTreeInner ) 
--- ShortDate         (childnode - this data comes from  dtTreeInner ) 
--Address             (childnode of Expressions  - this data comes from  dtTree)
```

[image: treeview]

**How do I automate this process with `for` loops?**

**Note: I am trying to create `TreeView` in ASP.NET MVC**

```
public class Node
{
    public int NodeID { get; set; }
    public string NodeName { get; set; }
    public string NodeText { get; set; }
    public eNodeType NodeType { get; set; }
    public List <Node> Childern { get; set; }
    public string NodeParent { get; set; }
    public string FirstParent { get; set; }
}

List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();
    nodes.Add(
                new Node() //Expressions
                {
                    NodeID = 0, NodeName = "nExp", NodeType = eNodeType.Exp, NodeText = "Expressions", 
                    Childern = new List<Node>()
                    {
                       new Node () //Standard
                       {
                           NodeID = 1,NodeName = "Standard",NodeType = eNodeType.Exp,NodeText = "Standard",NodeParent ="Expressions",FirstParent="Expressions",
                            Childern = new List<Node>()
                            {
                                 new Node () {NodeID = 2, NodeName = "[*Application Reference]",NodeType = eNodeType.Data,NodeText = "[*Application Reference]",NodeParent ="Standard",FirstParent="Expressions" },
                                 new Node () {NodeID = 3, NodeName = "[*Application status]",NodeType = eNodeType.Data,NodeText = "[*Application status]",NodeParent ="Standard",FirstParent="Expressions"},
                                 new Node () {NodeID = 4, NodeName = "[*Long Date]",NodeType = eNodeType.Data,NodeText = "[*Long Date]",NodeParent ="Standard",FirstParent="Expressions"},
                                 new Node () {NodeID = 5, NodeName = "[*Short Date]",NodeType = eNodeType.Data,NodeText = "[*Short Date]",NodeParent ="Standard",FirstParent="Expressions"}

                            }
                       }
}
```

Comment: Looks more like a recursion than like a for loop.

Comment: exactly but how do i do it my data is in two different datatables